# Javascript: Changing css using for loop function

Tags: javascript

I want to increase the margin-top px value of the ball element every time I click the button. What is wrong with my code?

```
let ballMargin = ball.style.marginTop;

moveButton.addEventListener('click', function moveDown() {
    for (let i = 0; i < ballMargin.length; i++) {
        ballMargin[i] += '10px';
    }
});
```

Comment: `ballMargin` is a string. Why do you expect your loop to accomplish with `ballMargin === "20px"` (just an example)? And why a loop at all? o.O

Comment: @Andreas Hi Andreas, good point. How would you go about writing it properly? I need help

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> Debug the situation. Find a way how to convert a string into a number. Manipulate the number. Modify the element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let ballMargin = 10;

moveButton.addEventListener('click', function moveDown() {
    ballMargin += 10;
    ball.style.marginTop = ballMargin + 'px';
});
```

Comment: You can avoid creating `ballMargin` variable by getting `marginTop` each time: `ball.style.marginTop = parseInt(ball.style.marginTop) + 10 + 'px';`

Comment: Thank you @Hett

Answer (score 2):

I make a simple example. I hope it's useful for you

```js
let moveButton = document.getElementById("moveButton");
let ball = document.getElementById("ball");
ball.style.marginTop = "10px";

moveButton.addEventListener("click",function (){

   ball.style.marginTop = parseInt(ball.style.marginTop) + 10 + "px";

})
```

```css
#ball{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<button id="moveButton">Move Button</button>
<div id="ball"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using loop u can use this

```
let ballMargin = $(ball).marginTop;
$('#id').addEventListener('click', function(){
$('#id').css({ marginTop : ballMargin + 10 + 'px' });
}
```

Comment: What is `$`? It cannot be jQuery otherwise `.marginTop` (why does `$()` return the `.style` property?) and `.addEventListener()` wouldn't work. But then `.css()` would not work. This answer doesn't work at all...